# function with dot(.) and comma(,) put together

Tags: r, rhadoop

```
map_wc <- function(.,lines)                                              
{                                                                        

  lines_lst = unlist(strsplit(lines,"\r\n",fixed=TRUE))                  
  l_cnt<-1;
  keys_l<-c()
  data_l<-c()
  for (line in lines_lst)
  { 
    words = unlist(strsplit(line,";",fixed=TRUE))

    if (length(words) != 5){
      next
    }
  }
```

Anyone using Rhadoop might be familiar with the code above. Can someone please explain to me the reason why ".," i.e dot(.) and (,) in the first line function are placed side-by-side. Please when answering note that am new to R.

Comment: Comma separates function arguments and dot is a valid symbol in R.

Comment: I assume the dot argument is used later in the function.